# Importing MYSQL table to RDS from a csv file

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have been searching all over the web and have been unable to find a solution to the following issue.
I need to automate a simple CSV file import into an RDS MySQL database. Normally I would push or pull this file to the MySQL database and then perform a "LOAD DATA INFILE" but I do not have access to the command line of the RDS box. The second option is to run mysqlimport, but again I do not know how to initiate this from the RDS box. I Googled for hours and cannot find an adequate answer. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download [MySql Utilities](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/utilities/) to install mysqlimport on your local machine.
2. Run mysqlimport with --host

> ```
> mysqlimport --local \
>         --compress \
>         --user=username \
>         --password \
>         --host=hostname \
>         --fields-terminated-by=',' Acme sales.part_*
> ```

```
--host - RDS endpoint (mysql–instance1.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com) 
--username - Your RDS Username
--password - Your RDS Password
```

Ref: [Importing Data From Any Source to a MySQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.AnySource.html)